# Dictionary int:variable(reference) in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new in python. I want have dictionary with const int key and string variable value
for example

```
>> queue {8080:var}
>> queue [8080]= "text"
>> var
text
```

in C can do it by store reference by how do t in python?
thanks

Comment: Python has no concept of constant values - it operates by a gentlemans agreement in terms of implementation. If you want to ensure that a user of an interface doesn't use the API in the wrong way - you have to write defensive code.

Comment: You can't do that in Python.  You would have to make `var` be some mutable object, but even then you couldn't change it with a simple `queue[8080] = "text"` unless you also made `queue` a custom object that helps out.

Comment: Try reading [this](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html) if you would like to know how dictionaries work

Comment: a cheap way would just be to put `var = queue[8080]` after assigning it, but if you already have it stored in `queue[8080]` adding a new variable in the mix almost seems pointless... unless the key was really really long, i wouldn't personally bother.

Comment: thanks for all replays. mutable object was my answer.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks from [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn) and all other answers

```
 >>> var = mutable_structure("text")
 >>> queue  = {8080:var}
 >>> queue [8080]
 text
 >>> var.setValue("editedText")
 >>> queue ['a']
 editedText
```

An implementation might look like

```
 class mutable_structure:
   def __init__(self, val):
     self.val = val

   def __repr__(self):
     return self.val
```